# returning by value and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, composition

So I have a storage class that has a ton of basic functionality that is really useful as is. It has move constructors to allow return by value.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A(){}
    A(const A& a);
    A(A&& a);
    A& operator=(const A& rhs);
    A& operator=(A&& rhs);
    int foo();//example member function
    //example function returning by value, elision and RHR make it efficient
    static A Foo();
};
```

This is great because it allows who own A to be very well defined. If I start needed to have inherited classes that extend A, AND the return statement of a call function to have polymorphism, is the only "correct" way to use smart pointers? AKA

```
class B_interface : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B_interface(){}
    virtual void FooBar() = 0;
};

class B : public B_interface
{
public:
    virtual ~B(){}
    B(const B& a);
    B(B&& a);
    B& operator=(const B& rhs);
    B& operator=(B&& rhs);
    virtual void FooBar() override;
    static shared_ptr<B> idontlikeit();
}
```

I thought of a (probably bad) way to get around it: if, instead of inheritance, use composition: the class contains something akin to a impl ptr:

```
class B_interface
{
public:
    virtual void FooBar() = 0;
};


class B : public A
{
    shared_ptr<B_interface> impl_;//could use 
public:
    B(const A& a,shared_ptr<B_interface> interface)//or some smarter way to pass this in
    : A(a)//call a's copy constructor
    {
       impl_.reset(interface);
    }//this constructor thinks

    void FooBar() { impl_->FooBar();}
    virtual ~B(){}
    B(const B& a);
    B(B&& a);
    B& operator=(const B& rhs);
    B& operator=(B&& rhs);
    static B ilikeitbetter();
}
```

So I like using the class better with that one, but making the class kinda stinks with that one...also, the B_interface might not make much sense outside B...Do you guys have any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, runtime polymorphism requires dynamic allocation and pointers. Derived classes can be (and usually are) of different size than base classes, so code expecting value semantics would not know how large a block to reserve for the value type.

In this specific case, consider returning a `unique_ptr<Interface>` if you don't expect the caller to require shared semantics. That way you don't force the caller to do reference counting if they don't need it. (The caller can always transfer ownership from the `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` if they want shared semantics)

Comment: Yeah, the composition way is just kinda ugly...It solves the space problem by making the class "jagged", but is just...ugly. Thanks for the response!